# How do i destroy my GameObject when the player enters its trigger?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can't seem to get my balloon (gameobject) to destroy when my player enters its trigger.
Does anyone know how to do this?
I tried to use collisions but it didn't work.
this is the collision script that didn't work (it was on the balloon)

```
public class PistolPickup : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Player")
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            Debug.Log("Destroyed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `collision.gameObject` is the *player* you want `this.gameObject`

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what you mean

Comment: @ImNotAGingerBreadIPromise it means you need to `Destroy(this.gameObject);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should understand the difference between a **OnCollisionEnter** event and **OnTriggerEnter** event. The former triggers when gameobjects **touch** and the latter when one **overlaps** the others trigger.

For both of the mentioned methods to work the objects have to have colliders on them. But depending on which above method you choose, you should also check the **IsTrigger** option on the collider accordingly.

So assuming al of the above is done you can make your code look like this:

```cs
public class PistolPickup : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Player")
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            Debug.Log("Destroyed the pickup.");
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: for the code to work you have to check **IsTrigger** option on the pickup objects collider.

Comment: One of your objects also needs a rigidbody, and its also important to note, that the rigid bodies and colliders need to be of the same dimension type aka 2d or 3d, you cannot mix them.